# Циклическая ссылка в модулях

Tags: delphi

Избитая ситуация, но не знаю наиболее адекватного решения. Например, есть два класса:

```
TParent = class
    child: TChild;
end;

TChild = class
    parent: TParent;
end;
```

Классы, конечно, описаны в разных модулях. Соответственно, модуль с `TParent` нужно подключить в `TChild` и наоборот. При этом, подключение в разделе `implementation` невозможно, а подключение в разделе `interface` вызовет циклическую ссылку.

Интересуют методы решения проблемы, а, в частности, - ответы на такие вопросы:

1. Правильна ли такая ситуация с точки зрения `ООП`?
2. Если нет, то как правильно?

Comment: Опишите оба класса в одном модуле, используя так называемый [forward declaration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Classes_and_Objects_%28Delphi%29#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes). Плюсы: меньшее количество модулей, отсутствие цикличности. Минус: увеличение объема модуля с описаниями классов (два класса вместо одного).

Comment: @Dima, это можно сделать, но это не выход, так как классы совершенно разные (даже не наследуются), и таких будет довольно много: если описывать все в одном модуле, это может в дальнейшем привести к путанице.

Comment: `Forward declaration` - то есть, завести модуль с объявлением всех классов типа:

    `TParent = class;
    TChild = class;
    TSubChild = class(TChild);`

И затем этот модуль подключать для избежания цикличности?

Comment: Нет, не модуль подключать с такими объявлениями классов, но сделать такое объявляение в *том же модуле*, где находится реализация классов. Еще один момент: классы самописные? Если да - почему бы не отнаследовать их от одного предка? Проблема с цикличностью исчезнет.

Comment: @Dima, да, самописные. Наследование от одного предка приведет, как минимум, к необходимости постоянного приведения типов при вызове объектов этих классов и при такой циклической связи.

Comment: Такая зависимость, конечно, не очень хорошая вещь и лучше изменить архитектуру так, чтобы child-у не нужно было знать о parent. Разорвать зависимость можно ещё через интерфейсы, т.е. в отдельном юните описываете интерфейс `IParent = interface ...` с методами, которые нужны чайлду и подключаете уже его. Соответственно, child будет хранить и общаться не с объектом, а с интерфейсом.